# UICollectionView don't show the cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

There is `UIViewController` which contain `UICollectionView`. Also there is `UICollectionViewCell` which has own class & XIB (CurrentCell.h, CurrentCell.m, CurrentCell.xib).

In my `UIViewController.h`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collection;
```

In my `UIViewController.m`:

```
@synthesize collection;
```

In **viewDidLoad**:

```
[self.collection registerClass:[CurrentCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellCurRecipe"];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(120, 90)];
[flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 10, 5, 10)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
[self.collection setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

In **cellForItemAtIndexPath**:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellCurRecipe";    
CurrentCell *cell = (CurrentCell *)[self.collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];   
Recipes *recipe = [currRecipesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];  
[cell.image setImage: recipe.image]; 
return cell;
```

**But:** if I tap intuitively to the cell **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** method calls.

EDITED

**Now everything works!**

I forgot to init the cell in CurrentCell.m:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurrentCell" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
            return nil;
        }

        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Register the nib, not the class. You should only need to register a class if the cell is made completely in code. If you use a xib, then register that (with registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:). If you make the cell in a storyboard, then don't register anything.

Comment: Thank you! I simply forgot to init the cell in class (See my answer).