# Designing UICollectionViewCell in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have never used `UICollectionViewController`s, and I thought that they were somewhat similar to `UITableViewController`s, but to my surprise, I cannot add UI elements to my custom `UICollectionViewCell`s  in the same way as I do with custom `UITableViewCell`s.

In fact, I can add labels, buttons, etc. in the Interface Builder, but when I run the application, the cells appear empty.

I have registered the cell class during the `viewDidLoad` method by calling `(void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`, and I've checked that I am returning a valid instance of `UICollectionViewCell`in the `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201574/uicollectionview-dont-show-the-cell/18201639#18201639. See my answer there. It's not quite the same problem, but my answer will fix your problem.

Answer (score 31):

My full explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880).

Create a custom class for the UICollectionViewCell:

```
import UIKit
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // have outlets for any views in your storyboard cell
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}
```

In the storyboard make the cell use this class

[image]

And set the Identifier for the cell

[image]

Don't use the `registerClass...forCellWithReuseIdentifier` in `viewDidLoad`. But you will refer to it in `collectionView...cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    return cell
}
```

Hook up the outlets from the Views in your storyboard cell to the `MyCollectionViewCell` class.

Comment: How do i connect labels in custom class to story board?

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir, Control drag from the label in the storyboard to the `@IBOutlet` label in the code.

Comment: When I do this, I can see what I put in my custom cell, but the selection of the cell isn't triggering at all. If I use the `registerClass` setup, then I can detect when you tap a cell, but the label I put in my storyboard isn't connected. (which makes sense, because I'm not registering the storyboard version).  How can I get selection to work with the setup shown in this example? (Note: I have two collectionViews in my ViewController - the other one uses a xib file as it's got more complex contents.

Comment: Update - when I put my cell in a xib, I was able to get both selection and the label on the cell to work. I suspect this is a bug in xcode storyboards. I'm using Xcode 12.2.

Answer (score 4):

@Suragch is spot on. I had this problem too: my UICollectionViewCell prototype's contents did not show in the cell when it got drawn.

The critical line is: "Don't use the registerClass...forCellWithReuseIdentifier in viewDidLoad". Really, *don't*. Not just "there is no need to", but "if you do register, it will stop your cell prototype from loading properly".

This only applies to Storyboard-based code, not .xib-based.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use registerClass...forCellWithReuseIdentifier, then you should do it this way:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "TrackCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "trackCellIdentifier")
```